# Django ORM - Grouped aggregates with different select clauses

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, ranking, django-orm

Imagine we have the Django ORM model `Meetup` with the following definition:

```
class Meetup(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField()
    speaker = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

I'd like to use a **single** query to fetch the language, speaker and date for the
latest event for each language.

```
>>> Meetup.objects.create(language='python', speaker='mike')
<Meetup: Meetup object>
>>> Meetup.objects.create(language='python', speaker='ryan')
<Meetup: Meetup object>
>>> Meetup.objects.create(language='node', speaker='noah')
<Meetup: Meetup object>
>>> Meetup.objects.create(language='node', speaker='shawn')
<Meetup: Meetup object>
>>> Meetup.objects.values("language").annotate(latest_date=models.Max("date")).values("language", "speaker", "latest_date")
[
    {'speaker': u'mike', 'language': u'python', 'latest_date': ...}, 
    {'speaker': u'ryan', 'language': u'python', 'latest_date': ...}, 
    {'speaker': u'noah', 'language': u'node', 'latest_date': ...}, 
    {'speaker': u'shawn', 'language': u'node', 'latest_date': ...}, 
]
```

D'oh! We're getting the latest event, but for the wrong grouping!

It seems like I need a way to `GROUP BY` the `language` but `SELECT` on a different
set of fields?

---

**Update** - this sort of query seems fairly easy to express in SQL:

```
SELECT language, speaker, MAX(date)
FROM app_meetup
GROUP BY language;
```

I'd love a way to do this without using Django's `raw()` - is it possible?

**Update 2** - after much searching, it seems there are similar questions on SO:

- [Django Query that gets the most recent objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories)
- [How can I do a greatest n per group query in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111590/how-can-a-do-a-greatest-n-per-group-query-in-django)
- [MySQL calls this sort of query a group-wise maximum of a certain column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

**Update 3** - in the end, with @danihp's help, it seems the best you can do
is two queries. I've used the following approach:

```
# Abuse the fact that the latest Meetup always has a higher PK to build
# a ValuesList of the latest Meetups grouped by "language".
latest_meetup_pks = (Meetup.objects.values("language")
                                   .annotate(latest_pk=Max("pk"))
                                   .values_list("latest_pk", flat=True))

# Use a second query to grab those latest Meetups!
Meetup.objects.filter(pk__in=latest_meetup_pks)
```

---

This question is a follow up to my previous question:

[Django ORM - Get latest record for group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887075/django-orm-get-latest-record-for-group)

Comment: Bummer that this is MySQL.  In postgres, you can directly use DISTINCT ON to get the latest by group [shameless plug for my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20129229/1309332).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of queries that are easy to explain but hard to write. If this be SQL I will suggest to you a CTE filtered query with row rank over partition by language ordered by date ( desc )

But this is not SQL, this is django query api. Easy way is to do a query for each language:

```
languages = Meetup.objects.values("language", flat = True).distinct.order_by()
last_by_language = [  Meetup
                     .objects
                     .filter( language = l )
                     .latest( 'date' )
                     for l in languages
                    ]
```

This crash if some language don't has meetings.
The other approach is to get all max data for each language:

```
last_dates = ( Meetup
             .objects
             .values("language")
             .annotate(ldate=models.Max("date"))
             .order_by() )

q= reduce(lambda q,meetup: 
     q | ( Q( language = meetup["language"] ) & Q( date = meetup["ldate"] ) ), 
     last_dates, Q())  

your_query = Meetup.objects.filter(q)
```

Perhaps someone can explain how to do it in a single query without raw sql.

**Edited** due OP comment

You are looking for:

```
"SELECT language, speaker, MAX(date) FROM app_meetup GROUP BY language"
```

Not all rdbms supports this expression, because all fields that are not enclosed into aggregated functions on select clause should appear on group by clause. In your case, `speaker` is on select clause (without aggregated function) but not appear in group by.

In mysql they are not guaranties than showed result `speaker` was that match with **max date**. Because this, we are not facing a easy query.

Quoting [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
>   to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
>   GROUP BY clause...**However, this is useful primarily when all values
>   in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same
>   for each group.**

The most close query to match your requirements is:

```
Reults = (   Meetup
             .objects
             .values("language","speaker")
             .annotate(ldate=models.Max("date"))
             .order_by() )
```

Comment: Using list comprehension with a queryset will generate a database hit for each language. I think your second example is the best way without using raw sql, but you need to join the `Q` objects with `&` instead of `^`.

Comment: @knbk, thanks about your comments. Also, thanks to fix `and` error. I have wrote from my mind ... not tested. Also, for few languages (3 or 4) first approach is also valid, you agree?

Comment: Yes, the first approach is also valid for few languages, but even with just 2 distinct languages, you'll generate more queries than with the second method.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm looking to do this using a single query! It seems? trivially easy to express the query in SQL:

    SELECT language, speaker, MAX(date)
    FROM app_meetup
    GROUP BY language;

I feel like there should be some way to make it happen in Django without resorting to `.raw()` :|

Comment: @danihp well that sucks :) I'll extend my question with additional information I found - at this point, I think the answer is "Depending on your DB, you probably can't."