# Django orm get latest for each group

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am using Django 1.6 with Mysql.

I have these models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique = True)

class Score(models.Model):
     student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
     date = models.DateTimeField()
     score = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get the latest score record for each student.
I have tried:

```
Score.objects.values('student').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

and:

```
Score.objects.values('student__username').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

as described [Django ORM - Get the latest record for the group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887075/django-orm-get-latest-record-for-group)
but it did not help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should work on Django 1.2+ and MySQL:

```
Score.objects.annotate(
  max_date=Max('student__score__date')
).filter(
  date=F('max_date')
)
```

Comment: this takes ages to run!

Comment: @emisilva I don't believe there is a more efficient way with this data structure and database backend.  If you need it to be faster - either add an index or refactor the data structure.

Comment: This is reeaaaallly slow if you have a lot of Scores.

Comment: Just for the record: This solution generates N^2 rows and filter them (N=Score count) that is not useful if N is larger than some thousands. Better to do one O(N) query and find `max_date` of each student and then issue another query do get actual `Score` objects. or use @Rohan's answer if you are on Postgres.

Answer (score 84):

If your DB is postgres which supports [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) on field you can try

```
Score.objects.order_by('student__username', '-date').distinct('student__username')
```

Comment: unfortunately i am using mysql

Comment: You may run into issues when trying to aggregate such query: `NotImplementedError: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.`

Comment: It's important to not call things like `.update()` on this queryset. As of 1.11, this will silently do the wrong thing.

Comment: Will this also work if I prefix the `order_by` with a `filter_by`?

Comment: @NirIzr yes, put the filter before the `order_by()` and it should work as expected.

Comment: this is why i love postgresql

Comment: I think it now works with all officially supported databases since the documentation does not say it's specific to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Unfortunately as of Feb 2021, it's not supported by CloudSQL in GAE.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this would give you the student and the data

```
Score.objects.values('student').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

If you want the full `Score` records, it seems you will have to use a raw SQL query: [Filtering Django Query by the Record with the Maximum Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020313/filtering-django-query-by-the-record-with-the-maximum-column-value)

Answer (score 1):

Some great answers already, but none of them mentions [Window](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) functions.

The following example annotates all score objects with the latest score for the corresponding student:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import FirstValue

scores = Score.objects.annotate(
    latest_score=Window(
        expression=FirstValue('score'),
        partition_by=['student'],
        order_by=F('date').desc(),
    )
)
```

This results in the following SQL (using Sqlite backend):

```sql
SELECT 
  "score"."id", 
  "score"."student_id", 
  "score"."date", 
  "score"."score", 
  FIRST_VALUE("score"."score") 
  OVER (PARTITION BY "score"."student_id" ORDER BY "score"."date" DESC) 
  AS "latest_score" 
FROM "score"
```

The required information is already there, but we can also reduce this queryset to a set of unique combinations of `student_id` and `latest_score`.

For example, on PostgreSQL we can use [distinct with field names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct), as in `scores.distinct('student')`.

On other db backends we can do something like `set(scores.values_list('student_id', 'latest_score'))`, although this evaluates the queryset.

<s>Unfortunately, at the time of writing, it is [not yet possible](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333#comment:33) to filter a windowed queryset.</s>

EDIT: [as of Django 4.2, windowed querysets can be filtered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.2/#models)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example using `Greatest` with a secondary `annotate`. I was facing and issue where annotate was returning duplicate records ( Examples ), but the `last_message_time` Greatest annotation was causing duplicates.

```py
qs = (
            Example.objects.filter(
                Q(xyz=xyz)
            )
            .exclude(
                 Q(zzz=zzz)
            )
            # this annotation causes duplicate Examples in the qs
            # and distinct doesn't work, as expected
            # .distinct('id') 
            .annotate(
                last_message_time=Greatest(
                    "comments__created",
                    "files__owner_files__created",
                )
            )
            # so this second annotation selects the Max value of the various Greatest
            .annotate(
                last_message_time=Max(
                    "last_message_time"
                )
            )
            .order_by("-last_message_time")
    )
```

reference:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest
- `from django.db.models import Max`