# Python Query list for oldest date

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary, time

My query returns the following in a list:

```
"Alex";"275467125";"2015-02-03 02:55:36-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2015-01-13 02:09:39-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2015-01-05 04:13:35-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-27 04:55:47-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-27 04:54:52-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-07 03:13:24-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-04 03:34:56-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-02 04:16:33-05";"1"
"Ali";"275464747";"2016-02-17 10:52:12-05";"2"
"Alladin";"275467455";"2016-03-13 06:51:52-04";"2"
"Alladin";"275467455";"2016-03-13 06:51:47-04";"2"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-26 03:56:41-04";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-26 03:55:21-04";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-21 23:04:28-04";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-02-12 13:24:44-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-12-03 08:20:35-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-11-09 04:18:27-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-11-09 04:11:59-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-09-13 21:27:12-04";"1"
```

I want to create a dictionary of person's name with the oldest record they have. I've figured out:

```
oldestlist = {d[0]:d[2] for d in records}
```

This returns a correct answer but my worry is that if I am presented a list that is not formatted in a descending order of date/time it will not provide the correct answer. What is the best way to create a dictionary with a name and the oldest date?

Comment: So is `records` actually a list? If it is, what types of data does it contain, is it `["Anna" (string), id (int), record_date (datetime), some_other_int (int)]` or all strings?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if you gave an actual python list.

Comment: @PavelGurkov you are correct in your data assignments. They are not all strings

Comment: @roganjosh I apologize on it not being an actual list. I did a quick copy and paste from my pg admin query page.

Comment: @Echelon_One It's fine, I managed to convert it and got close to an answer but I've just suspended while I check something

Comment: @Echelon_One, what formats are the dates in, are the -x is8601 offests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to sort any data, just use a *defaultdict* and check the current date vs any new date and update accordingly:

```
s = """"Alex";"275467125";"2015-02-03 02:55:36-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2015-01-13 02:09:39-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2015-01-05 04:13:35-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-27 04:55:47-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-27 04:54:52-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-07 03:13:24-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-04 03:34:56-05";"1"
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-02 04:16:33-05";"1"
"Ali";"275464747";"2016-02-17 10:52:12-05";"2"
"Alladin";"275467455";"2016-03-13 06:51:52-04";"2"
"Alladin";"275467455";"2016-03-13 06:51:47-04";"2"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-26 03:56:41-04";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-26 03:55:21-04";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-21 23:04:28-04";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-02-12 13:24:44-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-12-03 08:20:35-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-11-09 04:18:27-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-11-09 04:11:59-05";"1"
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-09-13 21:27:12-04";"1"
"""

import  csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(str)
for name,_, date, _ in csv.reader(s.splitlines(), delimiter=";"):
    if not d[name] or d[name] > date:
        d[name] = date


from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
 {'Alex': '2014-12-02 04:16:33-05',
 'Ali': '2016-02-17 10:52:12-05',
'Alladin': '2016-03-13 06:51:47-04',
'Anna': '2015-09-13 21:27:12-04'}
```

because the dates are in the *y-m-d time* format it is safe to do a  lexicographical comparison.

Comment: But surely this only works if the input is ordered... and that was the concern in the original post?

Comment: @roganjosh, why would it need to be ordered? we only update the users value if the date was newer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm sorry, but don't you think that timezones (-04, -05, at least they look like timezones) will interfere?

Comment: I'm reluctant to challenge you but you appear to display the opposite of what the OP expects (they want the _oldest_ record, while you display the newest) and they are concerned that their results will not be returned in chronological order, so they want some level of sorting - "This returns a correct answer but my worry is that if I am presented a list that is not formatted in a descending order of date/time it will not provide the correct answer.". So it works fine with their current data, but only because that happens to be sorted.

Comment: @roganjosh, I had it backwards initially, I edited before you comment to get the oldest, sorting makes no difference at all, Where are you getting the notion that the order is relevant, if I did `max([1,3,1,2,5,1])` would I not get the max value?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I need to go away and test `if not d[name] or d[name] > date: d[name] = date` to check my understanding :)

Comment: @roganjosh, it is basically the same as setting `mx = None` then `for ele in some_iterable:if ele is None or ele > mx: mx = ele`, we don't care about order as we are guaranteed to find the max/greatest value

Comment: Upvote, you taught me something and it's cleaner than my suggestion by far :)

Comment: @PavelGurkov, there may be some edge cases  but I don't think so, we are comparing by year-m-day time first, we would have to have matching values for everything up to the second before we would even hit the offset and if we did we would be in the same offset.  Worst case we could consider the offset and still do it in O(n) time

Comment: @roganjosh, no worries.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, what I meant is that in the sample dataset there are records with different offsets for the same user. So while lexicographical ordering works for this dataset, it may not be correct for any, for example for dates `2016-10-10 10:00:00-04` and `2016-10-10 09:00:00-06` (2PM vs 3PM UTC)

Comment: @PavelGurkov, the user would have to be in two different places with different offsets, we are not comparing different users against each other, we are comparing each users own dates. As I mentioned we can take the offset into account anyway  if needed but until the OP replies with more info then we are only guessing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I really like this answer and you are right I'm only looking for the posters first post date which then gets written to a field in my database table. I have other processes and functions that do other data time analysis on my data.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit frustrating to get your given "list" into an actual list format. If you can't deal with this task in the query itself, you could try:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = '''"Alex";"275467125";"2015-02-03 02:55:36-05";"1",
"Alex";"275467125";"2015-01-13 02:09:39-05";"1",
"Alex";"275467125";"2015-01-05 04:13:35-05";"1",
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-27 04:55:47-05";"1",
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-27 04:54:52-05";"1",
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-07 03:13:24-05";"1",
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-04 03:34:56-05";"1",
"Alex";"275467125";"2014-12-02 04:16:33-05";"1",
"Ali";"275464747";"2016-02-17 10:52:12-05";"2",
"Alladin";"275467455";"2016-03-13 06:51:52-04";"2",
"Alladin";"275467455";"2016-03-13 06:51:47-04";"2",
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-26 03:56:41-04";"1",
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-26 03:55:21-04";"1",
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-03-21 23:04:28-04";"1",
"Anna";"275467401";"2016-02-12 13:24:44-05";"1",
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-12-03 08:20:35-05";"1",
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-11-09 04:18:27-05";"1",
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-11-09 04:11:59-05";"1",
"Anna";"275467401";"2015-09-13 21:27:12-04";"1"'''

broken_list = lst.split(',')
stripped = [item.replace('\n', '') for item in broken_list]

rebuilt = []
for line in stripped:
    line = line.split(';')
    rebuilt.append([item.strip('"') for item in line])

# Now actually sorting this        
grouped = []
for key, group in groupby(rebuilt, key=itemgetter(0)):
    grouped.append(list(group))

sort_grouped = [sorted(item, key=itemgetter(2)) for item in grouped]
#sort_grouped = 

oldestlist = {d[0][0]:d[0][2] for d in sort_grouped}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need last record for each `name` instead of doing it explicitly with the `dict` make your queryset to perform `GROUP BY` on name. In Django you can do that using `.annotate` as is mentioned here: [Django Orm get latest for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923877/django-orm-get-latest-for-each-group)

Hence, your querset should be like:

```
YourModel.objects.values('name_column').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

---

*Additional piece of information*, you should be using [`order_by(-your_date_column)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) with your queryset in order to ensure data is always returned in desc order where `-` ensure desc order when list is needed.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to want the order inside the dict, he wants the dict to contain names as keys and the oldest record time for particular user as values.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty close. The answer I found that works best was a tweak of my original code but using the sorted() function.

For the newest I'd do:

```
newestlist = {d[0]:d[2] for d in sorted(records)}
```

For the oldest I'd do:

```
oldestlist = {d[0]:d[2] for d in sorted(records, reverse=True)}
```

Thanks to everyone who answered. I'll keep in mind the django references for if I use a queryset.

Comment: But have you checked what this sorts by? Muddle your records up, what makes it sort by date and not name?

Comment: After I started testing further I realized if my records were muddled to begin with I'd run into this exact issue.