# Django + postgres: orderby + distinct + filter() - strange behaviour

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have 2 simple models: Claim and ClaimStatus. Claims can have many statuses (eg. 1: Not analyzed yet, 2: Being analyzed, 3: Analyzed), all of which are written down in the database, together with claim_id and creation_date.
The model of interest here - ClaimStatus - is created the following way:

```
class ClaimStatuss(models.Model):
    status =  models.IntegerField(choices=investigated_choices, default=1)
    claim_id = models.ForeignKey('Claim', to_field='claim_id')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My aim is to select claims and their last (= active) statuses for filtering to show eg. all cases that are being analyzed at the moment, using the advice fron this thread:
[Django orm get latest for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923877/django-orm-get-latest-for-each-group)

TO make it simpler, I have just 2 objects in my database:

```
id: 6,claim_id: 578, status: 2, date: 2017-04-12 16:55:25.371014+00:00
id: 7,claim_id: 578, status: 3, date: 2017-04-12 17:04:06.944270+00:00
```

I do the following:

1. Select all ClaimStatuss objects, and group them to have the latest one for each claim_id (only one in this example):

```
statuses = ClaimStatuss.objects.all().order_by('claim_id','-creation_date').distinct('claim_id')
```

2. I check, if only one, the latest element has been selected for the queryset:

```
statuses.get().status
    3
```

3. Now I filter this one-element Queryset, to leave only the objects, which contain status=2

```
statuses.filter(status=2).get().status
    2
```

And I see, that my Query containing just one object with status "3", after filtering found also the object with status "2"!

I presume that's the problem with the first command, but is this an expected behavior (if so, what am I doing wrong / what should I do to make it work) or some bug?

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:

Checking for the status=3 brings positive results too (All other statuses don't)

```
>>> statuses.filter(status=3).get().status
3
```

Weirdly enough, I can execute the get method on statuses variable, which just proved to contain 2 different objects:

```
>>> statuses.get().status
3
```

The ForeignKey is not the problem here - I tried changing it to String and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about the interaction between the `distinct()` call and the rest of the filter.

All `distinct('claim_id)` will do is ensure that one item per claim is returned. But you only ask for one item; when you add the filter for status=2, you still only get one item for the distinct value of claim_id. That it's not the same one you get if you don't add the filter is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, I do understand it now, thank you. Do you know any way to overcome the problem. i.e. return only one element per claim instead of just "ensuring" one is returned each time?

Comment: OK, I solved the problem by adding a Boolean column called Is_current, which stores information about the given status being up to date. Then when the new status is added it changes the Is_current column value to False for the previous status (the one, with "True") before adding new object (with Is_current=True). At the end, I just filter values with Is_current=True.

Comment: Good solution. The problem is that doing queries like this dynamically depends on subqueries, which Django has only just [added support for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) (in 1.11).