# Prefetch related starting from a single object - geting first in second prefetch and count and order

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 Models Product,Company Categories.

```
class Product(Meta):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

I need:

- to get all the products of a company
- show  the product first category
- count the number products per company and show
- order products by reverse updated_at

I start from:

```
1. Company.objects.get(pk=company_pk).prefetch_related('products')
```

will give me an error, because get returns an object:

```
class CompanyProductListView(ListView):
 model = Company
 template_name_suffix = '_company_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    company_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    return Company.objects.get(pk=company_pk).prefetch_related('products')
```

get without prefetch works.

2. `return Company.objects.filter(pk=company_pk).prefetch_related('products')`

there is no error, but in template:

```
 {% for company in company_list %}
        {{ company.name}}
    {% endfor %}
```

I loop even is one, but doesn't show me anything.

Besides that I need to attach first category to each product, and count the number of products

I'm thinking on access something like this:

```
{{company.name}}

{% for product in company.products %}
   {{ product.name }}
   {{ product.category }}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire code for your 2nd solution. I don't see why the for loop won't work unless it found no objects with pk=company_pk. It probably seems like a typo/silly mistake.

Comment: @oxalorg I added the CBV code, in template is just what you see

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I need to attach first category to each product"? On what basis do you define "first"? (date added?)

Comment: @oxalorg   first, the creation date so the category id, I know that there is a first() method for Queryset; attach Whe I show in html, at the top I show some fields about company than product.name, product desc, product category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will get a little complicated, but should help you solve your issue.

*PS: I haven't tested this but should mostly work. Will take a deeper look once I get some more time.*

First we get the company we want:

```
company = Company.objects.get(pk=company_pk)
```

Then we fetch all the first categories for all products, it can be done by using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923877/django-orm-get-latest-for-each-group#19924129) as a guide:

```
first_categories = Category.objects.order_by('product__id', '-id').distinct('product__id')
```

Now we use the first_categories to use to limit the amount of data we prefetch (giving this a different perspective, we will query the `Product` model instead of the `Company` model)

```
product_list = Products.objects.filter(company=company).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('categories', queryset=first_categories)
)
```

---

```
def get_queryset():
    company_pk = ...
    company = ...
    first_categories = ...
    product_list = ...
    return product_list
```

Comment: thanks, but now being three will not work overwriting the get_queryset,  so I need to keep one in queryset and add the others in context ?

Comment: @user3541631 You need the `company` and `first_categories` only to get the `product_list`. Since your CBV is `CompanyProductListView`, you need a list of products. So jsut return the product_list as the query set. I've updated the answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: thanks, but in this case how to I access in template also company info ? I update my question to see how I want to access the context in template