# Django ORM get maximum value of a field and corresponding other column values

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
`exp_no`   'time'   'price'
```

---

```
  1       0:00:00     20.0
  1       7 days      45.0
  1       15 days     100.0
  2       0:00:00     20.0
  2       7 days      45.0
  2       15 days     100.0
```

The corresponding Django model:

```
class StData(models.Model):
      exp_no = models.ForeignKey(StIndex, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      time = models.DateTimeField()
      price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to make a smaller table which would have exp_no, max_time and corresponding price such that:

```
 `exp_no`   'time'   'price'
```

---

```
  1       15 days     100.0
  2       15 days     100.0
```

In pandas, I'd do `df.groupby('exp_no')['time', 'price'].max().reset_index()`
to get the desired table.

In Django ORM annotation to get the same result(or Queryset) if I do:

```
qs.values('exp_no').annotate(max_time=Max('time')).order_by()
```

it gives me exp_no and time, but I want to get the corresponding price as well. I have looked through this answer in SO: [Django orm get latest for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923877/django-orm-get-latest-for-each-group)

But not sure how I get the price. Using Django 2.0 with sqlite3.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question boils down to obtaining the `StData` object (or the values) for the record with the largest `time` column. So we do not need an aggregate, but obtain the smallest or largest row with respect to the `time` column.

## Obtaining the `StData` object with the maximum `time`

You can just obtain the `last()` row when you order on `'time'`, like:

```
stdata_max_time = qs.order_by('time').last()  # will return a StData
```

or alternatively:

```
stdata_max_time = qs.order_by('-time').first()  # will return a StData
```

In case `time` is NULLable (not here), you can ensure that you will not retrieve a row with `NULL` by specifying that when ordering these should be placed as first/last elements respectively:

```
from django.db.models import F

# two alternatives
stdata_max_time = qs.order_by(F('time', nulls_first=True)).last()
stdata_max_time = qs.order_by(F('-time', nulls_last=True)).first()
```

This is thus a `StData` object, and you can thus retrieve all relevant information you want from that object. Since it is a `StData` object, it will also behave like this (so extra properties, methods, etc. you defined, will work as well).

## Obtaining the values with the maximum `time`

This is completely similar, except that we put a `.values(..)` call in the query:

```
stdata_max_time = qs.order_by('time').values('exp_no', 'time', 'price').last()
```

But unless there are some really good reasons, I would personally prefer to fetch the `StData` object, since that means "*batteries included*" (you get all the logic you wrote in the `StData` class with that object).

Comment: Absolutely elegant. Cleared my concept as well. Thank you so much.