# Django ORM: Get maximum value of a field with corresponding other fields values

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have this Table (*Counters*):

| cell_id | tftralacc | tfnscan | thtralacc | thnscan | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13997 | 10 | 360 | 94 | 360 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 0 | 360 | 0 | 360 | 2022-02-22 01:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 0 | 360 | 0 | 360 | 2022-02-22 02:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 0 | 360 | 0 | 360 | 2022-02-22 03:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 36 | 360 | 83 | 360 | 2022-02-22 04:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 0 | 360 | 2 | 360 | 2022-02-22 05:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 1 | 360 | 15 | 360 | 2022-02-22 06:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 11 | 360 | 159 | 360 | 2022-02-22 07:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 21 | 360 | 409 | 360 | 2022-02-22 08:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 25 | 360 | 1282 | 360 | 2022-02-22 09:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 20 | 360 | 1201 | 360 | 2022-02-22 10:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 30 | 360 | 1381 | 360 | 2022-02-22 11:00:00+01 |
| 13997 | 42 | 360 | 924 | 360 | 2022-02-22 12:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 1 | 360 | 36 | 360 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 0 | 360 | 0 | 360 | 2022-02-22 01:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 1 | 360 | 0 | 360 | 2022-02-22 02:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 0 | 360 | 2 | 360 | 2022-02-22 03:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 0 | 360 | 0 | 360 | 2022-02-22 04:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 0 | 360 | 12 | 360 | 2022-02-22 05:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 3 | 360 | 4 | 360 | 2022-02-22 06:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 24 | 360 | 123 | 360 | 2022-02-22 07:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 31 | 360 | 374 | 360 | 2022-02-22 08:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 18 | 360 | 620 | 360 | 2022-02-22 09:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 38 | 360 | 1616 | 360 | 2022-02-22 10:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 36 | 360 | 1410 | 360 | 2022-02-22 11:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 24 | 360 | 957 | 360 | 2022-02-22 12:00:00+01 |

I want to get the specific *date_time* value of the maximum *traffic* (which is calculated based on the the fields *tftralacc*, *tfnscan*, *thtralacc* and *thnscan*) for every *cell_id*.

I've managed to get this maximum value for every *cell_id* by using the `annotate()` and `group_by()` functions of the Django's QuerySet API:

```
result = Counters.objects.filter(
    date_time__gte = date_start,
    date_time__lte = date_end
).annotate(
    # calculate the traffic for each row.
    traffic = Case(
        When(Q(tfnscan=0) or Q(thnscan=0), then=0),
        default = Round((F('tftralacc')*1.0/F('tfnscan')) + 
                        (F('thtralacc')*1.0/F('thnscan')), 2),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
).order_by('cell_id').values(
    # Group by cell_id.
    'cell_id'
).order_by().annotate(
    # calculate the max traffic for the grouped Cells.
    max_traffic = Max('traffic')
)
```

The calculated *traffic* for every *date_time* is demonstrated here:
[image]

My code successfully returns the maximum traffic for every *cell_id*:

| cell_id | max_traffic |
| --- | --- |
| 13997 | 3.92 |
| 14000 | 4.59 |

But my goal is to get the Corresponding *date_time* value for every max value. like this:

| cell_id | max_traffic | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13997 | 3.92 | 2022-02-22 11:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 4.59 | 2022-02-22 10:00:00+01 |

or

| cell_id | date_time |
| --- | --- |
| 13997 | 2022-02-22 11:00:00+01 |
| 14000 | 2022-02-22 10:00:00+01 |

Because that max value is just a mean to get the *date_time* and not the goal.

Note: There is this question that describes my problem, but its answer refers to a work-around solution, which is not possible with my problem.
[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543124/django-orm-get-maximum-value-of-a-field-and-corresponding-other-column-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`models.Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) with [`models.OuterRef`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) to join on `cell_id` field. Then use `queryset.annotate()` to annotate the subquery with `max_traffic`. Finally, use `queryset.filter()` to select rows that have `traffic` equals to `max_traffic` and use `.distinct()` to remove duplicate rows.

```py
counters_with_traffic = Counters.objects.filter(
    date_time__gte=date_start,
    date_time__lte=date_end
).annotate(
    # calculate the traffic for each row.
    traffic=Case(
        When(Q(tfnscan=0) | Q(thnscan=0), then=0),
        default=Round((F('tftralacc') * 1.0 / F('tfnscan')) +
                      (F('thtralacc') * 1.0 / F('thnscan')), 2),
        output_field=models.FloatField()
    )
)

counters_with_max_traffic = counters_with_traffic.order_by('cell_id').values(
    # Group by cell_id.
    'cell_id'
).order_by().annotate(
    # calculate the max traffic for the grouped Cells.
    max_traffic=Max('traffic'),
).filter(cell_id=models.OuterRef("cell_id")).values("max_traffic")

result = counters_with_traffic.annotate(
    max_traffic=models.Subquery(counters_with_max_traffic),
).filter(
    traffic=models.F("max_traffic")
).values(
    "cell_id", "max_traffic", "date_time"
).distinct("cell_id", "max_traffic")
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I've got an exception error:
<class 'django.db.utils.ProgrammingError'>column "u0.date_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...eric(1000, 15), 2) END) AS "max_traffic", (SELECT U0."date_t...

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer. Could you try again?

Comment: Now, It works but, it does return all "date_time" and "traffic" values for every "cell_id"

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Does it help?

Comment: It gaves the same result, distinct here will not help because, all the returned values are distinct for every "cell_id", if it's not the "traffic", it's the "date_time"

Comment: Does it happen when all `traffic` of a `cell_id` have the same values or when `max_traffic` is duplicated?

Comment: I didn't notice until you mentioned that, Yeah, it does happen when the `max_traffic` is duplicated.