# Get the last and unique element of the list based on date

Tags: python, django, collections, django-queryset

Here is my data and code:

```
[
(datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Raport'), 
(datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 'Raport'), 
(datetime.date(2020, 3, 23), 'Raport'),

(datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Document'), 
(datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 'Document'), 
(datetime.date(2020, 3, 23), 'Document'),

(datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Analize'), 
(datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 'Analize'), 
(datetime.date(2020, 3, 23), 'Analize'),
]
```

Here is django (2.2) code:

```
sorted(DataSet.objects.values_list('doc_type', flat=True).distinct(), reverse=True)
```

I need to get the last and unique element of each document `doc_type` together with the date. At the moment I have the same list of documents:

```
['Raport', 'Document', 'Analize']
```

but I need:

```
[(datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Raport'), (datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Document'), (datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Analize')]
```

Can someone provide me some hint?
Thanks.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: I am using Sqlite @IainShelvington

Comment: @Webdev does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923877/django-orm-get-latest-for-each-group

Answer (score 1):

If a Python solution fit your needs, use a dictionary to group and find the maximum:

```
import datetime

data = [
    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Raport'),
    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 'Raport'),
    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 23), 'Raport'),

    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Document'),
    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 'Document'),
    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 23), 'Document'),

    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Analize'),
    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 24), 'Analize'),
    (datetime.date(2020, 3, 23), 'Analize'),
]

groups = {}

for date, group in data:
    if group not in groups:
        groups[group] = date
    elif date > groups[group]:
        groups[group] = date


result = [(v, k) for k, v in groups.items()]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Raport'), (datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Document'), (datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), 'Analize')]
```

This solution has `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am gratefull. Please tell me if exists some django WuerySet methods to get the same results?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done in a QuerySet method with SQLite as the DB engine

Comment: OK, I will change it on Postgres but I would like to know also solution with djnago's methods