# Show only latest records in Django Admin

Tags: django-admin

Given a Django Admin module for a model that has fields for an ID and datetime, is it possible to show only the latest entity for each group defined by ID?

Would it be possible to do with a filter and have it applied by default?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you could override get_queryset() ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)) and filter however you like.
Eg:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.order_by('user_id', '-date').distinct('user_id')
```

Note distinct() will only work with positional arguments like this if you're using PostgreSQL (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct))

See also these answers:

[Override get_queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12354293/18556111)

[Filter latest by field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924129/18556111)