# Django Query: Group by field and get the latest entry per group

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following table in Django-1.11:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(...)
    active = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

It would be great if the `slug` was a foreign key to avoid duplicate values    but this is not the case, I am coping with a third party app.

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, 'slug': 'test-1', 'active': 'datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 18, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>)'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'slug': 'test-1', 'active': 'datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>)'}, 
    {'id': 3, 'slug': 'test-2', 'active': 'datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 10, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>)'},
    {'id': 4, 'slug': 'test-2', 'active': 'datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>)'},
]
```

I am looking for a query which will return the latest entry with slug `test-1` and the latest entry with slug `test-2`.

[Using `annotate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887075/django-orm-get-latest-record-for-group) I just receive the results with their datetime:

```
Market.objects.values('slug').annotate(Max('active'))
Out[11]: <QuerySet [
{'active__max': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 18, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'slug': 'test-1'},
{'active__max': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'slug': 'test-1'},
{'active__max': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 10, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'slug': 'test-2'},
{'active__max': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 10, 43, 8, 581046, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'slug': 'test-2'}
]>
```

This result does not seem to follow [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses). What am I doing wrong? Is it the `SlugField` that does not permit "grouping"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need to add empty `order_by()` by the [default-ordering-or-order-by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) in the result query can be added extra fields to the group by.

try it:

```
Market.objects.values('slug').annotate(Max('active')).order_by()
```